# isVideoOffered() not working in sinch Android/IOS

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, sinch

I have IOS and Android app using sinch video and Audio (App to App ) calling integrated.
isVideoOffered() Bool always gives video irrespective of incoming call.I want to receive audio screen when audio call is called from another app(Android/IOS) and video if video call is initiated from another app(Android/IOS).

Code for Android to differentiate incoming call(video or audio)

```
 public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {
        if( call.getDetails().isVideoOffered()){
            Log.d(TAG, "Incoming call");
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this,      IncomingCallScreenActivityVideo.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Incoming audio call");
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingCallScreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Code for IOS to differentiate incoming call(video or audio)

```
 #pragma mark - SINCallClientDelegate

 - (void)client:(id<SINCallClientDelegate>)client didReceiveIncomingCall:(id<SINCall>)call {


   if (call.details.applicationStateWhenReceived == UIApplicationStateActive) {

    if([call.details isVideoOffered]) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"callView" sender:call];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"audioCallView" sender:call];

    }
}
else {
        [call answer];
}
}
```

Comment: do you care to explain about what sinch is and how you are using it or do we need to research for it and provide answer to you ?

Comment: What are the reasons for downvote ?

Comment: Sinch is App to App calling(video/audio) API service

Comment: We can't help with the info you provided. Provide code that is related to the issue and also provide relevant details of what code should do.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this is a bug and we will fix it for a future beta release.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.Can you please tell me when is the next scheduled release ? So that i can inform my client .

Comment: Its now aviaible frod download

Comment: hi @cjensen  i tried to register user for video call using a name on two different devices from same username. Somehow it is calling on first device how to make it available for only latest registered user. I know we can user stopClient method but in my conditions i can't use it. Please help me out of this

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using your VideoActivity layouts and classes for handling both the calls because when an audio call is received, the video portions remain hidden in your layout..

Additionally, you can set an icon that can tell you whether you're on Video Call or not.. I mean you can do somethink like.

```
@Override
public void onVideoTrackAdded(Call call) {
    // Display some kind of icon showing it's a video call
    isVideo=true;
}
```